# How to filter a belongsToMany relationship? Laravel 5.4

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5, has-and-belongs-to-many

I've created an application to filter data. Inside of index, I made a filter to filter products by description, model, status, stock and category.
My category is organized through the `erp_categoy` table and the relationship with the product is made through `erp_product_category` (Receiving Product ID + Category ID).
I created a BelongsToMany relationship in the Model: Product, Category and ProductCategory.

**Product Model**

```
public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category', 'erp_product_category', 'erp_productid', 'erp_categoryid');
    }
```

**Category Model**

```
public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product','erp_product_category', 'erp_categoryid', 'erp_productid');
    }
```

**Product_category Model**

```
public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Product', 'erp_categoryid', 'erp_categoryid');
    }
```

In my index I created a select one that lists all categories of the 'erp_category' table.

```
<select id="categoria" name="categoria" class="form-control" style="width: 150px;">
                                @foreach($cat as $categoria)
                                    <option value="{{$categoria->erp_categoryid}}" @if($categoria->erp_categoryid === session('categoria')) selected  @endif >{{$categoria->erp_name}}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
```

I've extended my JavaScript and stored the values in a session 'category'.

```
<script src="{{ asset('assets/js/ProductSearch.js') }}"></script>
    <script>
        var postSearch = '{{ route('product::searchPost') }}';
        var searchRequest = {
            'categoria' :'{{session('categoria')}}',
        };

    </script>
```

And then I did the research through JS.

```
$(document).on('blur', '#categoria', function(){
        var categoria = $('#categoria').val();
        searchRequest['categoria'] = categoria;
        doSearch();
    });

function doSearch() {
    $.post(postSearch, {
            'search_data': JSON.stringify(searchRequest),
            '_token': $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content'),
        }
        , function(data) {
            $('#product-table').html(data);
        });
}
```

I was expecting the product-table (table I created to return the values). I list my products through the category entered by select, but it returns the initial list of the index.

**Product-table**

```
<td>
    @foreach($prod->category as $categoria)
    {{$categoria->erp_name}}
    @endforeach
</td>
```

**Controller**

```
public function search(Request $request)
{    
 $product = Product::query();
 $categoria = Category::query();
if ($request->isMethod('post'))
{
$data = json_decode($request->search_data);
$categoria;
$categoria = $data->categoria;
session(['categoria' => $categoria]);
if(strlen(session('categoria')) > 0)
{
 $product_ids = Product::whereHas('category', function ($query){
   $query->where('erp_category.erp_categoryid', '=', session('categoria'));
   })->get();
    $ids = [];

          foreach($product_ids as $product_data)
          {
              $ids[] = $product_data->erp_productid;
          }

          $product = $product->whereIn('erp_category.erp_categoryid', $ids);
      }
        $content = $product->paginate(10);
        $cat = Category::all();

        if ($request->isMethod('post'))
        {
            return view('admin.product-table')->with('product', $content)->with('cat',$cat);
        } else
        {
            return view('admin/product')->with('product', $content)->with('cat',$cat);
        }
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Where are you using `search_data` to search after the post call?

Comment: @Laerte I forgot to put my controllers. I already fixed it. Sorry.

Comment: If you `dd($content);` the results are what you are expecting?

Comment: @Laerte My dd returned data from the start table, without organizing through the category.

Comment: If you `dd($product_ids);` before `$ids = []`; what are the results? The `whereHas` query seems to be right, but maybe it is not going in the if clause and paginating an empty query.

Comment: When I dd ($ product_ids), it returns the right values. I also tested my query through the Workbench. It returned the right values, but in the table it does not organize :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143408/discussion-between-laerte-and-vinicius-rosa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your code to something like this:

```
$content = null;
if(strlen(session('categoria')) > 0) {
    $product_ids = Product::whereHas('category', function ($query){
        $query->where('erp_category.erp_categoryid', '=', session('categoria'));
    });
    $content = $product_ids->paginate(10);
    $cat = Category::all();
}

if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
    return view('admin.product-table')->with('product', $content)->with('cat',$cat);
} else {
    return view('admin/product')->with('product', $content)->with('cat',$cat);
}
```

And then the view:

```
@if ($product !== null)
    @foreach($product as $p)
        <td>
            @foreach($p->category as $categoria)
                {{$categoria->erp_name}}
            @endforeach
        </td>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

The problem in the controller must be happening when you call `whereIn` or something like this. Probably you don't need to query Produto again.

The second thing is that you are not using the results in the view. You are calling the relationship function.

Try this and check if it helps...

Comment: It still gives the same error, I've already created similar questions and I still can not solve it. From what I've seen, you're Brazilian too. I do not want to take advantage, but would you have skype or something? I'm a bit desperate with this mistake.

Comment: Let's talk in chat